# How to open transaction in Filter

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I use spring 3.2.4 and create a Filter. This Filter has to start the transaction. In other words what I want to implement :

```
beginTransaction()
chain.doFilter(request, response);
endTransaction()
```

I tried to use @Transactional annotation with doFilter method but this apparently does not work (TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive(); returns false). Then I added OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter before my filter to obtain the entityManager but

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;
```

still returns null. Is there any way to open the transaction in spring so that transaction interceptor knows about it?

Comment: Why do you want to open a transaction in a filter... IMHO that is a bad way of managing your transactions, not to mention uncontrollable. Your service-layer should be the transactional boundary, not your web-layer.

Comment: That is true but almost whole service layer is legacy code and I can not change anything there.

Comment: Welcome to the world of AOP :). You can do some nasty... ehr nice things with that. But basically autowiring doesn't work in filters **UNLESS** you use a [DelegatingFilterProxy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/DelegatingFilterProxy.html) to have the bean configured in spring. Instead of doing all the things yourself I would wrap the doFilter in a [TransactionTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html)

Comment: Thanks. But then I still have to provide the PlatformTransactionManager to the Filter to init TransactionTemplate. How can I resolve that without AOP?

Comment: If you configure the filter in the ApplicationContext you can simply autowire or inject it into the filter. Then in your web.xml configure a DelegatingFilterProxy.

Comment: ok thanks that helped me to solve the problem